# Is electron-hole pair thermal equilibrium in semiconductors a dynamic or static equilibrium?

Tags: solid-state-physics, semiconductor-physics, equilibrium

In my textbook, it is mentioned that electron hole pairs in semiconductors  are formed due to thermal energy and at a given temperature the number of electrons and holes is constant. The formula given is

$$n(e)\cdot n(h)=\text{constant}$$

where $n(e)$ is the number density of electrons and $n(h)$ is the number density of holes.

Is this a dynamic equilibrium (e.g., chemical equilibrium, reaction for production of ammonia, etc.) where electron-hole pairs are continuously forming due to thermal energy and recombining or is it a static equilibrium?

The expression is also suspiciously similar to expression of equilibrium constant in chemistry. Doping is also similar-looking to addition of a strong acid or base to water.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, electron-hole pair generation and recombination is a dynamic equilibrium. In fact the equation you mentioned in the question, i.e.
$$n_e \times n_h= \text{constant}$$
is nothing but the consequence of **The Law of Mass Action**, which is widely used where dynamic equilibriums are concerned.

See [this](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mass_action_law_(electronics)) to learn more about the application of the law of mass action in electronics.

Comment: Thanks! So is the "action" in this case the number density of charge carriers?

Comment: Exactly! This is perfectly analogous to its chemical equilibrium counterpart. However, the real rigorous proof of this law of mass action which we have "extended" might not be this trivial.